# how to show an index.html page from an webserver on node.js

Tags: node.js

I am really new on node.js. I try this, but it just open a blank page. What am I doing wrong??

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, html) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(html);
    response.end();
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
});
```

Comment: I've tried this code and it works perfectly fine on me. Are you sure the index.html file is present in the right folder? It should be in the same folder where you launch nodeJS

Comment: Are you sure `index.html` isn't empty?

Comment: There is something in the Index file and it is in the same folder also

Comment: If I just write plain text in the index.html file it show the text, but I got an css file in there to and cannot show the styles that I have been making

Answer (score -1):

it's better to use express.js to create web-server on node

http://expressjs.com/

but I prefer to change jade to ejs like app.engine:)